# Pgfplots ignores my last datapoint

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, bar-chart, missing

Datapoint `e` will get ignored regardless of whether `d` - the previous datapoint - exists or not. I want `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e` to be present in the plot in a bar plot that groups the bars by two (so feel free to play around).

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            title=ML Model Training,
            ylabel=Elapsed Time (seconds),
            xlabel=ML Model,
            ybar interval=0.7,
            symbolic x coords={a, b, c, d, e},
            xtick=data,
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {
            (a,157.9)
            (b, 2.99)
            (c, 11.71)
            (d, 91.5)
            (e, 406.3)
        };
        \addplot coordinates {
            (a,57.9)
            (b, 12.99)
            (c, 21.71)
            (d, 21.5)
            (e, 106.3)
        };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

Now even if I comment out `d` from the symbolic coordinates and the coordinates list, `e` is still not shown:

[image]

What am I missing please?

<kbd>[Live Demo](https://www.overleaf.com/3882816345hgnggnsxjzzg)</kbd>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `ybar interval` but `ybar` (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122610/47927)):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            title=ML Model Training,
            ylabel=Elapsed Time (seconds),
            xlabel=ML Model,
            ybar=0.7,
            symbolic x coords={a, b, c, d, e},
            xtick=data,
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {
            (a, 157.9)
            (b, 2.99)
            (c, 11.71)
            (d, 91.5)
            (e, 406.3)
        };
        \addplot coordinates {
            (a, 57.9)
            (b, 12.99)
            (c, 21.71)
            (d, 21.5)
            (e, 106.3)
        };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to get a similar appearance to your original plot, you can use `xminorgrids=true, minor tick num=1` to add the vertical lines again, remove the major ticks with `major tick style={draw=none}` and finally adjust the spacing with `enlarge x limits=0.125`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            title=ML Model Training,
            ylabel=Elapsed Time (seconds),
            xlabel=ML Model,
            ybar=0.7,
            xminorgrids=true,
            minor tick num=1,
            symbolic x coords={a, b, c, d, e},
            xtick=data,
            typeset ticklabels with strut,    % align tick labels vertically
            major tick style={draw=none},     
            enlarge x limits=0.125
        ]
        \addplot coordinates {
            (a, 157.9)
            (b, 2.99)
            (c, 11.71)
            (d, 91.5)
            (e, 406.3)
        };
        \addplot coordinates {
            (a, 57.9)
            (b, 12.99)
            (c, 21.71)
            (d, 21.5)
            (e, 106.3)
        };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Jasper, thanks a lot for your answer. With this approach it loses the vertical grey line that existed, like a limit (margin?) between each 2-group bars, i.e. between `a` and `b` for instance. Does it make sense what I am saying?

Comment: @gsamaras see my edit.